# Android: memory leaks when using shared EGL context

Tags: android, memory-leaks, opengl-es, egl

I use `TextureView` for displaying a OpenGL graphics. I have a few `TextureView` screens. Also I have a lot of graphic content such as sprites or text glyphs, and I don't want to create it again when screen is swithed. I found that EGL shared context can help me.

```
val surfaceAttributes = intArrayOf(
    EGL14.EGL_WIDTH, 1,  
    EGL14.EGL_HEIGHT, 1,
    EGL14.EGL_NONE
)
sharedSurface = EGL14.eglCreatePbufferSurface(display, config, surfaceAttributes, 0)

val contextAttributes = intArrayOf(
    EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
    EGL14.EGL_NONE
)
sharedContext = EGL14.eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextAttributes, 0)
```

I use these context and surface as global objects. Whe application starts I load all necessary for me resources. For each TextureView I create a new `EGLContext` with `sharedContext`:

```
val context = EGL14.eglCreateContext(display, config, sharedContext, contextAttributes, 0)
```

It works fine but there is a poblem with a memory leak. I destroy `EGLContext` and `EGLSurface` asitiated with `TextureView` in `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` method but a graphics memory doesn't free after destroying a `TextureView` object (I checked it via Profiler).

I found that all memory frees only after destroyng my `sharedContext`.

Is there any way free from memory leaks to preserve OpenGL resources (sprites, glyphs) during all applications life time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very dummy solution which doesn't allow to flow out of memory and to have a lot of TextureViews on different screens. I just keep my TextureView as a static object and in a fragment's onCreateView method I place my keeped TextureView in a special placeholder view.

It works because as it turned out these memory leaks related with destroying and creating of TextureView.

If you don't destroy TextureView then a memory leak won't happen.